# Character keeps moving

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to create a stamina script, where you can only use rb.AddForce (movement) if you have stamina, else you shouldn't be able to move.

Here is my code so far (with help from here):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PhysicsBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float maxStamina; // from the editor
    public float staminaReconveryRate; // from the editor
    public float staminaDrainRate; // from the editor
    public float joystickDeadband; // from the editor
    private float currentStamina;
    public float nothing;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        currentStamina = maxStamina;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        // Make sure the player actually ask to move; this is done to avoid spending stamina when 
        // not expecting it
        bool hasHorizontal = false;
        bool hasVertical = false;
        if ( moveHorizontal > joystickDeadband )
            hasHorizontal = true;
        else
            moveHorizontal = 0.0f;

        if ( moveVertical > joystickDeadband )
            hasVertical = true;
        else
            moveVertical = 0.0f;

        // player requests to move
        if ( hasHorizontal || hasVertical )
        {
            // and has stamina
            if (maxStamina > 0.0)
            {
                // lets move him and consume stamina
                Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);

                rb.AddForce (movement * speed);

                currentStamina -= Time.deltaTime * 70;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // the player does not request to move, so we restore the stamina. 
            moveHorizontal = 0.0f;
            moveVertical = 0.0f;
        }

    }

    void Update () {
        Debug.Log (currentStamina);
    }


}
```

Some of the code may be irrelevant as I'm building it off another answer I got but I can't seem to fix some of the bugs:

- I can see the stamina decreasing to negative figures, which is good,
  but even after it becomes negative the character is still able to
  move normally.
- The character can only move UP and to the RIGHT, not BACK and to the LEFT??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line:

```
// and has stamina
if (maxStamina > 0.0)
```

Should be written like this:

```
if (currentStamina > 0.0)
```

because `currentStamina`determines if you can move or not.

As for the movement directions, I think these lines:

```
if ( moveHorizontal > joystickDeadband )
        hasHorizontal = true;
```

and

```
if ( moveVertical > joystickDeadband )
        hasVertical = true;
```

should be written as:

```
if ( Mathf.Abs( moveHorizontal ) > joystickDeadband )
        hasHorizontal = true;
```

and

```
if ( Mathf.Abs( moveVertical ) > joystickDeadband )
        hasVertical = true;
```

to get negative values (back and left)